# Linux rm file / folder with non printing characters "\032"

Tags: ubuntu, rm

`git status` shows:

> Untracked files:   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be
>   committed)
>
> ```
>     "\032"
> ```

`ls` shows that folder as

> ?

I've tried:

> $ rm "\032"
>
> rm: cannot remove '\032': No such file or directory
>
> $ rm \032
>
> rm: cannot remove '032': No such file or directory
>
> $ rm \\032
>
> rm: cannot remove '\032': No such file or directory

But as you can see from the output, the command did not work.

What invocation of `rm` should I be using?

Also, however did I manage to create such a file/folder?

Running 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Comment: Which OS is this? Please add an OS tag.

Comment: You could improve your question by letting us know what "none worked" actually means. Were there error messages or not, and which ones?

Comment: You could try `'\x32'` or `'\x032'`.

Comment: Thanks @Seth. didn't work: 
rm: cannot remove 'x32': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'x032': No such file or directory

Comment: Did you try with double quotes and did you include the backslash?